# Calculating minimum detectable effect from sample size and conversion rate

Tags: statistical-significance, multivariate-analysis, frequentist, extreme-value

I have a function for calculating the required sample size based on four inputs: baseline conversion rate, minimum detectable effect, confidence and statistical power:

```
baseline = A
MDE = B
confidence = C
power_level = D

if (baseline > 0.5) {
    baseline = 1.0 - baseline
}

t_alpha2 = ppnd(1.0 - confidence / 2)
t_beta = ppnd(power_level)

sd1 = Math.sqrt(2 * baseline * (1.0 - baseline))
sd2 = Math.sqrt(baseline * (1.0 - baseline) + (baseline + MDE) * (1.0 - baseline - MDE))

sample = (t_alpha2 * sd1 + t_beta * sd2) * (t_alpha2 * sd1 + t_beta * sd2) / (MDE * MDE)
```

Example: https://www.evanmiller.org/ab-testing/sample-size.html

What I am looking for a is a reversed version of this function where the sample size is an input and MDE is an output. All of the other inputs stay the same.